# pandas resampling for for nighttime hours

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a multivariate time series array. The timeseries is currently aggregated in 10 second intervals:

```
**Time**
2016-01-11 17:00:00
2016-01-11 17:00:10
2016-01-11 17:00:20
```

I want to resample so that I get a 5 hour timeframe per day (it doesn't matter how the time is shown in the data frame, just matters that its being aggregated properly). I am resampling by the mean values.

```
**Time**
2016-01-11 10:00:00-15:00:00
2016-01-12 10:00:00-15:00:00
2016-01-13 10:00:00-15:00:00
```

How would one do this?

Comment: @BenPap what do you mean by "then take the mean of the rest"? I will get too many intervals, how do I get rid of the unwanted intervals?

Comment: @QuangHoang yes that is precisely my question.

Comment: I mean if `'00:00:00-04:59:59'` is the first block, then `20:00:00-23:59:59` the last block?

Comment: @QuangHoang that's not what I want. I think I worded it pretty clearly in my question. I want 1 5 hour time interval per day.

Comment: Does it have to start from `10:00:00` or from `00:00:00` works?

Comment: it will take the mean of all the data between 10:00-15:00 every day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I would filter the time period I want and groupby day:

```
# mask the hours we want
hours = df.index.hour
mask = (hours >= 10) & (hours <=14)

# groupby
df[mask].groupby(df[mask].index.floor('D')).mean()
```

Toy data:

```
Times = pd.date_range('2016-01-11', '2016-01-14', freq='10s')

np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': Times,
                   'Value': np.random.randint(1,10, len(Times))})
```

gives:

```
            Value
Time    
2016-01-11  4.993333
2016-01-12  5.030556
2016-01-13  5.012778
```

Comment: I have a feeling this will work, but im currently getting the error '
AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'dt''

Comment: `DatetimeIndex` objects don't need to access via `dt`.

Comment: I forgot that your time is indexed. Just remove all `.dt` as @piRSquared says. Let me update.

Answer (score 0):

```
df.groupby([df['Time'].dt.month, df['Time'].dt.day]).apply(lambda x: x.set_index('Time').resample('5H').mean())
```

You will have to group by the month and day of your time column first, then apply a resampling to your Time column in 5H (5 hours), followed by `.mean()` which will take the mean of your other columns.

The reason for the groupby is that you dont want 5 hr intervals for all day every day, only for the times each day. As long as your times are within 5hrs you will only get one interval a day.

Comment: thanks so much for the answer, however when I ran this I didn't get what I want. It gives me the mean for every fifth hour. What I want is the mean for all the data between hours 10 and 15.

Comment: ```df = df[(df['Time'].dt.hour >= 10)&(df['Time'].dt.hour <= 15)].copy()``` you can filter it to get the times you want first, then run my above answer.

Comment: same problem, except now its isolated to the mean for the 10th hour and the mean for the 15th hour. I need the mean for all the time between 10:00 and 15:00.

Comment: change the 15 to a 14 on my comment's code. I was accidentally pulling an extra hour.